# Submitting a multidimensional array with file input via POST with php

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a php form that has a known number of columns (ex. top product, price, quantity, file(file input)), but has an unknown number of rows, as users can add rows as they need.

I am using a multidimensional array:

```
name="prod[0][name]"
name="prod[0][qty]"
name="prod[0][file]"
```

on post I use

```
 if ( isset( $_POST['prod'] ) )
    {

        foreach ( $_POST['prod'] as $value )
        {
            //some code here
if (isset($_FILES[$value["file"]]["name"]) && 
    ($_FILES[$value["file"]]["size"] > 0) &&
    ($_FILES[$value["file"]]["error"]==0) &&
    $_FILES[$value["file"]]["name"] != "" )
  {
   //code of uploading file

 } 

    }
```

My problem is I can't get the file to  be uploaded, I always get the error

> $value["file"] is undefined

**please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error correctly states that there is no `file` key in your array at that level. Instead you should use the key from the `foreach` loop.

On the top of my head, it should be something like:

```
foreach ( $_POST['prod'] as $key => $value ) {
                            ^^^^ this will be your numeric index
    //some code here
    if (isset($_FILES['prod']['name'][$key]['file']) ...
```

But you'd better do a `var_dump($_FILES['prod']);` to confirm that as I am not sure how php handles multi-level file upload arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the enctype attribute on the form element ?

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp